# Optimizing splay tree

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I wrote an splay search tree using the algorithm description and debug and now I want to find out how I can optimize it, maybe I have some obvious errors and I will be glad if someone shows them to me.

Java code:

```
private final class SplayTree{

    private Node root;

    private void keepParent(Node v){
        if(v.l != null) v.l.p = v;
        if(v.r != null) v.r.p = v;
    }

    private void rotate(Node parent, Node child){

        Node gparent = parent.p;
        if(gparent != null){
            if(gparent.l != null && gparent.l.k == parent.k)
                gparent.l = child;
            else
                gparent.r = child;
        }

        if(parent.l != null && parent.l.k == child.k){
           Node tmp = child.r;
           child.r = parent;
           parent.l = tmp;
        }else{
            Node tmp = child.l;
            child.l = parent;
            parent.r = tmp;
        }

        keepParent(child);
        keepParent(parent);
        child.p = gparent;
    }

    private Node splay(Node node){

        if(node == null)
            return null;

        while (node.p != null){
            Node parent = node.p;
            Node gparent = parent.p;
            if(gparent == null){
                rotate(parent, node);
            }else{
                if(gparent.l != null && gparent.l.k == parent.k && parent.l != null && parent.l.k == node.k){
                    rotate(gparent, parent);
                    rotate(parent, node);
                }else if(gparent.r != null && gparent.r.k == parent.k && parent.r != null && parent.r.k == node.k){
                    rotate(gparent, parent);
                    rotate(parent, node);
                }else{
                    rotate(parent, node);
                    rotate(gparent, node);
                }
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    private Node find(int key){

        Node node = root, prev = null;
        while (node != null){
            prev = node;
            if(node.k == key)
                break;
            else if(key < node.k)
                node = node.l;
            else
                node = node.r;
        }
        if(node == null) {
            node = prev;
            if(node != null) this.root = node;
        }
        else
            this.root = node;

        return splay(node);
    }

    public long sum(int l, int r){

        sum = 0;
        Node root = this.root;
        while (root != null){
            if(root.k >= l && root.k <= r)
                break;
            else if(root.k < l)
                root = root.r;
            else
                root = root.l;
        }
        if(root == null)
            return sum;

        Queue<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        queue.add(root);
        Node node;
        while ((node = queue.poll()) != null){

            if(node.k >= l && node.k <= r)
                sum += node.k;

            if(node.l != null)
                queue.add(node.l);

            if(node.r != null)
                queue.add(node.r);
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public Node[] split(int key){

        if(this.root == null)
            return new Node[]{null, null};

        Node subRoot = find(key);
        if(subRoot.k < key){
            Node right = subRoot.r;
            if(right != null) right.p = null;
            subRoot.r = null;
            return new Node[]{subRoot, right};
        }else{
            Node left = subRoot.l;
            if(left != null) left.p = null;
            subRoot.l = null;
            return new Node[]{left, subRoot};
        }

    }

    public Node insert(int key){

        if(root == null)
            return this.root = new Node(key);

        Node prev = null;
        while (root != null){
            prev = root;
            if(root.k == key)
                return splay(root);
            else if(key < root.k)
                root = root.l;
            else
                root = root.r;
        }
        root = prev;

        Node node = new Node(key);
        if(key < root.k){
            root.l = node;
            node.p = root;
        }else{
            root.r = node;
            node.p = root;
        }

        return this.root = splay(node);
    }

    public Node merge(Node l, Node r){

        if(r == null)
            return l;
        if (l == null)
            return r;

        l = maximum(l);
        l.r = r;
        r.p = l;

        return l;
    }

    public Node remove(int key){

        Node root = find(key);
        if(root == null || root.k != key)
            return root;

        if(root.l != null) root.l.p = null;
        if(root.r != null) root.r.p = null;

        return this.root = merge(root.l, root.r);
    }

    public Node maximum(Node root){

        while(root.r != null)
            root = root.r;

        return splay(root);
    }

}

private final class Node{
    int k;
    Node l;
    Node r;
    Node p;

    Node(int k) {
        this.k = k;
    }
}
```

It would also be interesting to know if there are any mistakes in the style of the code. I will be glad to any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things that I noticed. This first being a potential change in structure in `find`. You could handle the else branch instead of (effectively) setting a flag indicating whether you used a `break`. This keeps similar logic together, but at the cost of introducing another exit point to your function, which can be considered bad in some styles.

```
private Node find(int key){

    Node node = root, prev = null;
    while (node != null){
        prev = node;
        if(node.k == key)
            this.root = node;
            return splay(node);
        else if(key < node.k)
            node = node.l;
        else
            node = node.r;
    }

    if(prev != null) this.root = prev;
    return splay(prev);
}
```

The other potential change I want to point out is in `splay`. You have some inconsistency in your `if` nesting. You should probably stick to all `else if`s, it makes it easier to draw comparisons between the 4 cases, and reduces unnecessary indentation. You should also consider wrapping the two particularly long conditionals, so that you can control where they wrap if they are opened on a 80 character-wide terminal, and can abuse the symmetry within each conditional to help expose any copy/paste errors.

```
private Node splay(Node node){

    if(node == null)
        return null;

    while (node.p != null){
        Node parent = node.p;
        Node gparent = parent.p;
        if(gparent == null){
            rotate(parent, node);
        }else if(gparent.l != null && gparent.l.k == parent.k
               && parent.l != null &&  parent.l.k == node.k){
            rotate(gparent, parent);
            rotate(parent, node);
        }else if(gparent.r != null && gparent.r.k == parent.k
               && parent.r != null &&  parent.r.k == node.k){
            rotate(gparent, parent);
            rotate(parent, node);
        }else{
            rotate(parent, node);
            rotate(gparent, node);
        }
    }

    return node;
}
```